# Secure cookies prevent login in PHP/Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, cookies

Has anyone used the directive session.cookie_secure when also using 
Zend_Captcha_Image? When enabled, every time I try to login it fails.  Essentially 
each request is treated as a new session, therefore failing the captcha verification even when I type it in correctly. I have been using Zend_Captcha_Image for several months without any problems and when the session.cookie_secure directive is removed, it works fine.

I have tried just using the session.cookie_secure directive in the php.ini 
file. (this is not how I'm doing it now, but I included it here so you know).

Currently I'm calling `Zend_Session::setOptions(array('cookie_httponly' => true, 'cookie_secure'   => true ));` in the application bootstrap. I have turned on & off `resources.session.cookie_secure = true` to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why should it work when you add `session.cookie_secure` directive to the php.ini directly? Have you read what default options `Zend_Session::start()` uses on the [official manual page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html)?

Comment: PHP.ini --> I don't remember the exact syntax. My point is that when I turn on secure cookies in php.ini I get the same results. Yes, I have read the manual.

Comment: Ok, in this case you need get cookie settings from you php.ini with [session_get_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php) and set them with `Zend_Session::setOptions()` in your bootstrap file. I guess domain and/or path in your php.ini and Zend_Session config are different.

Comment: You are going over https right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cookie_secure` setting only works over SSL. Do not set it unless you have SSL enabled with a certificate on your sever. Usually, you would enable this for use on the production site and disable it on the development servers.